# Why has my existing Nginx failed to run after rebooting the system which says 13: Permission denied, although chmod 777?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, selinux

My Nginx configured with docker.
but when I reboot my system my existing nginx failed to run, I face the error message: [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.
It's the [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) mode issue. First I check current SELinux mode.
`$ getenforce`
Here is: Enforcing
So it needs to be Permissive.
`$ setenforce [Permissive|0]`

To make changes persistent through a system reboot, edit the 'SELINUX=' line in  /etc/selinux/config  for either 'enforcing', 'permissive', or 'disabled'. For example: 'SELINUX=permissive'